# Is there a way to disable or interact with the chrome pane with selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium to write tests with JavaScript specifically. When we are running our tests we want the browser to either have notifications disabled or this pane to close. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuwOk.png)

This is causing some errors that we do not want.

I have attempted a variety of courses as noted in the selenium docs to handle alerts and popups but they haven't worked in this case.

```
var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();

var chromeOptions = {
    'args': ['--disable-notifications']
};
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);

exports.chromeOptions = chromeOptions;
```

I have also tried to build the driver with these capabilities to disable notifications but again this hasn't worked. After going down the rabbit hole I have come to ask my question here.

I'd appreciate a solution to my trap! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on this, it is outside of Selenium's control meaning you should find another option with chrome args.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).